# Google Script , If Form submission is the same, dont email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With the generous help from the stackoverflow community, I was able to create a google script for the pools that I run that notifies me if there are abnormal readings for the pools from a google form submission that one of my Aquatic Specialists would fill out.

What I am struggling now with is that I have three pools and if someone submits a form for Pool A, it will notify me. If someone else submits a form for Pool B and if Pool A's readings are still the same, it will notify me for both.

Is there a way for me to write in google script :

If all of Pool A's values are the same as the previous , 
do not email out again

If all of Pool B's values are the same as the previous , 
do not email out again

If all of Pool C's values are the same as the previous , 
do not email out again

Here is my code:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//----vvvvvPool
  var IDPpHReading = sheet.getRange('A6:A7').getValue();
  var IDPpHTest = sheet.getRange('B6:B7').getValue();
  var IDPORP = sheet.getRange('A9:A10').getValue();
  var IDPSetPoint = sheet.getRange('B9:B10').getValue();

  var IDPCL = sheet.getRange('A12:A13').getValue();
  var IDP_Filter1_INF = sheet.getRange('A16:A17').getValue();
  var IDP_Filter1_EFF =  sheet.getRange('B16:B17').getValue();
  var IDP_Filter2_INF = sheet.getRange('A20:A21').getValue();
  var IDP_Filter2_EFF =  sheet.getRange('B20:B21').getValue();

  //vvvvv----SPA

  var SPApHReading =  sheet.getRange('C6:C7').getValue();
  var SPApHTest = sheet.getRange('D6:D7').getValue();
  var SPAORP = sheet.getRange('C9:C10').getValue();
  var SPASetPoint = sheet.getRange('D9:D10').getValue();
  var SPA_Filter_INF = sheet.getRange('C12:C13').getValue();
  var SPA_Filter_EFF = sheet.getRange('D12:D13').getValue();
  var SPACL = sheet.getRange('C15').getValue();


  //vvvvvvvvvvv---- Sports med
  // Hot Plunge

  var HPpHReading = sheet.getRange('E6:E7').getValue();
  var HPpHTest = sheet.getRange('F6:F7').getValue();
  var HPORP = sheet.getRange('E9:E10').getValue();
  var HPSetPoint = sheet.getRange('F9:F10').getValue();
  var HPCL = sheet.getRange('E12:E13').getValue();

  //vvvvvvvvvvvvv---- Cold Plunge
  var CPpHReading = sheet.getRange('G6:G7').getValue();
  var CPpHTest = sheet.getRange('H6:H7').getValue();
  var CPORP = sheet.getRange('G9:G10').getValue();
  var CPSetPoint = sheet.getRange('H9:H10').getValue();
  var CPCL = sheet.getRange('G12:G13').getValue();

  //vvvvvvvvvvvv---Swim EX
  var SEpHReading = sheet.getRange('I6:I7').getValue();
  var SEpHTest = sheet.getRange('J6:J7').getValue();
  var SEORP = sheet.getRange('I9:I10').getValue();
  var SESetPoint = sheet.getRange('J9:10').getValue();
  var SECL = sheet.getRange('I12:I13').getValue();


  //vvvvvvvvvvvv---ODP
  var ODPpHReading = sheet.getRange('K6:K7').getValue();
  var ODPpHTest = sheet.getRange('L6:L7').getValue();
  var ODPORP = sheet.getRange('K9:K10').getValue();
  var ODPSetPoint = sheet.getRange('L9:L10').getValue();
  var ODPCL = sheet.getRange('k12:k13').getValue();




// email addresses for people and subject

 var emailAddress = " PseudoMcFake@Notreal.noe";

  var subject = "Abnormal Readings";

  var view = "link";





// if soemthing is "wrong" then it changes this to true. At the end, all trues will be added to the email list
  var needsCheck = false;


      var message = 'An Aquatic Specialist recently logged chemical readings that were off. Here is a list for your convinience:\n';



//-------------------- IDP pH 


    if (IDPpHReading  > 7.8) {
      var message = message +  " \n IDP - ph Controller reading was too high at " + IDPpHReading ;
      var needsCheck = true;


    }
  else if  (IDPpHReading  < 7.2) {

      var message = message + " \n IDP - ph Controller reading was too low at " + IDPpHReading 
      var needsCheck = true;


    }
   if (IDPpHTest  > 7.8) {
     ;
      var message = message + " \n IDP - pH Test was too high at " + IDPpHReading 
      var needsCheck = true;

    }
  else if  (IDPpHTest  < 7.2) {

       var message = message + " \n IDP - pH Test was too low at " + IDPpHReading 

      var needsCheck = true;
    }
  //-------------------------------------------------------


  //-------------------------------------------------- Chlorine/ORP IDP
  if ( IDPORP >= IDPSetPoint + 20) {

     var message = message + " \n IDP - ORP reading was too high at " +IDPORP;

    var needsCheck = true;
  }
   else if ( IDPORP <= IDPSetPoint - 20) {

    var message = message + " \n IDP - ORP reading was too low at " + IDPORP;

        var needsCheck = true;

  }

   if ( IDPCL < 1) {

   var message = message + " \n IDP - Chlorine was too low at " + IDPCL;

     var needsCheck = true;
  }
    else if ( IDPCL > 5 || !isNaN(IDPCL) ) {

   var message = message + " \n IDP - Chlorine was too high at " + IDPCL;

     var needsCheck = true;
    }

        else if ( isNaN(IDPCL))
      {
        var message = message + " \n Spa - Chlorine reading was an 'error'. Might be too high. User input = " + IDPCL;
        var needsCheck = true;
      }







 //---------------------------------------------------------------

  //---------------------------------------------- Filters



  if ( IDP_Filter1_INF - IDP_Filter1_EFF >=10 || IDP_Filter1_EFF - IDP_Filter1_INF >= 10)
  {
   ;
   var message = message + " \n IDP - Differential greater than or equal to 10 for filter 1";
        var needsCheck = true;


  }

  if ( IDP_Filter2_INF - IDP_Filter2_EFF >=10 || IDP_Filter2_EFF - IDP_Filter2_INF >= 10)
  {

       var message = message + " \n IDP - Differential greater than or equal to 10 for filter 2";

        var needsCheck = true;


  }

  //-------SPA----------------------------------------------




   if (SPApHReading  > 7.8) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - pH Reading too high at " + SPApHReading;

     var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  (SPApHReading  < 7.2) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - pH Reading was too low at " + SPApHReading;

      var needsCheck = true;
    }
   if ( SPApHTest  > 7.8) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - pH test was too high at " + SPApHTest;

      var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  ( SPApHTest  < 7.2) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - pH test was too low at " + SPApHTest;

      var needsCheck = true;
    }
  //-------------------------------------------------------


  //-------------------------------------------------- Chlorine/ORP SPA
  if ( SPAORP >= SPASetPoint + 20) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - ORP reading was too high at " + SPAORP;

    var needsCheck = true;
  }
   else if ( SPAORP <= SPASetPoint - 20) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - ORP reading was too low at " + SPAORP;

    var needsCheck = true;
  }

   if ( SPACL < 2) {

     var message  = message + " \n SPA - Chlorine was too low at " + SPACL;

    var needsCheck = true;
  }
    else if ( SPACL > 5) {

      var message  = message + " \n SPA - Chlorine was too high at " + SPACL;

   var needsCheck = true;
    }
      else if ( isNaN(SPACL))
      {
        var message = message + " \n Spa - Chlorine reading was an 'error'. Might be too high. User input = " + SPACL;
        var needsCheck = true;
      }



  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Sports Med Hot Plunge ------------------------


   if (HPpHReading  > 7.8) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - pH reading was too high at " + HPpHReading;

      var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  (HPpHReading  < 7.2) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - pH reading was too low at " + HPpHReading;

       var needsCheck = true;
    }
   if ( HPpHTest  > 7.8) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - pH Test was too high at " + HPpHTest;

       var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  ( HPpHTest  < 7.2) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - pH Test was too low at " + HPpHTest;

       var needsCheck = true;
    }
  if ( HPORP >= HPSetPoint + 20) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - ORP reading was too high at " + HPORP;

     var needsCheck = true;
  }
   else if ( HPORP <= HPSetPoint - 20) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - ORP reading was too low at " + HPORP;
         var needsCheck = true;

  }

  if ( HPCL > 5) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - Chlorine  was too low at " + HPCL;

     var needsCheck = true;    
  }
  else if ( HPCL < 2) {

      var message  = message + " \n HP - Chlorine was too low at " + HPCL;

   var needsCheck = true
   }

    else if ( isNaN(HPCL))
      {
        var message = message + " \n HP - Chlorine reading was an 'error'. Might be too high. User input = " + HPCL;
        var needsCheck = true;
      }



  //-------------------------------------------------------
  // Cold Plunge


   if (CPpHReading  > 7.8) {

      var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - pH Reading was too High at " + CPpHReading ;
      var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  (CPpHReading  < 7.2) {

      var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - pH Reading was too low at " + CPpHReading ;      

var needsCheck = true;    
  }
   if ( CPpHTest  > 7.8) {

      var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - pH Test was too High at " + CPpHTest ; 
var needsCheck = truel     

    }
  else if  ( HPpHTest  < 7.2) {

      var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - pH Test was too low at " + CPpHTest ; 

      var needsCheck = true
}
  if ( CPORP >= CPSetPoint + 20) {

      var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - ORP reading was too High at " + CPORP ; 
    var needsCheck = true;

  }
   else if ( CPORP <= CPSetPoint - 20) {
  ;
      var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - ORP reading was too low at " + CPORP ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
  }

  if ( CPCL > 8) {

       var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - Chlorine was too High at " + CPCL ; 
    var needsCheck = true;

  }
  else if ( CPCL < 2.5) {

     var message  = message + " \n Cold Plunge - Chlorine was too low at " + CPCL ; 
    var needsCheck = true;

  }
   else if ( isNaN(CPCL))
      {
        var message = message + " \n Cold Plunge - Chlorine reading was an 'error'. Might be too high. User input = " + CPCL;
        var needsCheck = true;
      }

  //----------------------------------------------

  // Swim EX

   if (SEpHReading  > 7.8) {

        var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - pH Reading was too High at " + SEpHReading ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  (SEpHReading  < 7.2) {

     var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - pH Reading was too low at " + SEpHReading ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
   if ( SEpHTest  > 7.8) {

    var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - pH Test was too High at " + SEpHTest ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  ( SEpHTest  < 7.2) {

     var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - pH Test was too low at " + SEpHTest ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
  if ( SEORP >= CPSetPoint + 20) {

     var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - ORP reading was too High at " + SEORP ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
  }
   else if ( SEORP <= CPSetPoint - 20) {

    var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - ORP reading was too low at " + SEORP ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
  }

  if ( SECL > 8) {

  var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - Chlorine  was too High at " + SECL ; 
    var needsCheck = true;

  }
  else if ( SECL < 2.5) {
   var message  = message + " \n Swim EX - Chlorine  was too low at " + SECL ; 
      var needsCheck = true;

  }

   else if ( isNaN(SECL))
      {
        var message = message + " \n Swim EX - Chlorine reading was an 'error'. Might be too high. User input = " + SECL;
        var needsCheck = true;
      }



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  // ------------------ ODP
   if (ODPpHReading  > 7.8) {

        var message  = message + " \n ODP - pH Reading was too High at " + ODPpHReading ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
  if (ODPpHReading  < 7.2) {

        var message  = message + " \n ODP - pH Reading was too low at " + ODPpHReading ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
   if ( ODPpHTest  > 7.8) {

    var message  = message + " \n OFP - pH Test was too High at " + ODPpHTest ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
  else if  ( ODPpHTest  < 7.2) {

     var message  = message + " \n ODP - pH Test was too low at " + ODPpHTest ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
    }
  if ( ODPORP >= ODPSetPoint + 20) {

     var message  = message + " \n ODP - ORP reading was too High at " + ODPORP ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
  }
   else if ( ODPORP <= CPSetPoint - 20) {

    var message  = message + " \n ODP - ORP reading was too low  at " + ODPORP ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
  }

  if ( ODPCL > 5) {

  var message  = message + " \n ODP - Chlorine  was too High at " + ODPCL ; 
    var needsCheck = true;
   var ODPCL_2 = ODPCL;

  }
  else if ( ODPCL < 2) {
   var message  = message + " \n ODP - Chlorine  was too low at " + ODPCL ; 
      var needsCheck = true;

  }

 else if ( isNaN(ODPCL))
      {
        var message = message + " \n ODP - Chlorine reading was an 'error'. Might be too high. User input = " + ODPCL;
        var needsCheck = true;
      }





  if ( needsCheck)
  {
    var message = message + "\n Please check the situation asap. \n Here is a link to the spreadsheet -  " + view;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

  }





};
```

Edit:

I was thinking of doing something like

```
var IDP&Spa_LastRow = getLastRow();
var Previous_IDP&SPA = getLastRow() - 1;
```

but... the issue is when someone submits another form.

Comment: Have you considered caching each new submission via PropertiesService? If new submission is identical to the one retrieved from the PropertiesService service, stop executing the functionl

Comment: I have not!. I will definitely look into that.